# serverless angular 7 project on lambda api gateway with custom domain

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, api-gateway, custom-domain

I have deployed angular project to lambda with serverless, it is all working fine with aws domain https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/production/

but when I bind the custom domain to it, such as https://web.asx200.com.au
 with mapping to /, it shows me 
"message": "Forbidden"

if i map to /production with my custom domain, it shows "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " for all the bundled js files.

if i open the network tab to see the http status when trying to open those js, css files, it says 304.

I am running out of ideas. please anyone can help?

Comment: You need route53 to point your domain name `https://web.asx200.com.au` to API gateway

Comment: Have you used cloudfront to deliver your angular contents? if so need to point your cloudfront to route53 with your domain.

Comment: i think if i try to bind the custom domain, api gateway will generate a cloudfront domain and I have binded that domain to my dns server. (I am managing my dns outside of aws), in this case do I still need route53?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
npm run build:prod:deploy
```

instead of `npm run build:serverless:deploy`, this works for me.

> The script npm run build:serverless:deploy sets the base-href to '/production/' (take a look at the build:browser:serverless script in package.json).
> This seems like an inconsistency in Serverless Angular Universal and can lead to multiple problems with API Gateway stages or custom domains.

[Angular Serverless deployment to AWS appends base-href to url, causing redirect to 404error - angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54609104/)